# asp.net c# and mongodb models

Tags: c#, sql-server, mongodb, database

I wanna know if i can use mongodb like models (model classes) in my project (asp.net mvc 4 c#).

For example:

```
namespace Demo.Models
{

    public class Model1
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
        public string Genre { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
    }

    public class MovieDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Model1> models { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Let's say this is standard model for mssql database. Can i create models like this to use MongoDB collections, documents?
If yes, how? (if you can provide me with link of some examples).

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can don't forget to add BsonId attribute, because every object has to have his own unique id.

```
public class Model1
{
    [BsonId]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
    public string Genre { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

And example you can find here:

http://www.joe-stevens.com/2011/10/02/a-mongodb-tutorial-using-c-and-asp-net-mvc/

Comment: Thanks you, ill give a try in that example.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use mongodb as model in your  project. you just have to define a model class and get the required enetities that you need.But in this you have provide an `BsonId` attribute for any object for generating a unique id.

here's is a example from my code just check it out.

```
public class QuestionAttempt
{
    public ObjectId QId { get; set; }
    public long UserId { get; set; }
    [BsonElement("SN")]
    public string SkillName { get; set; }
    [BsonElement("IC")]
    public bool IsCorrect { get; set; }
}
```

In my code i have given some objects a smaller name with the `[BsonElement()]` attribute for less memory usage.